# Suppressing splog content from Google+ Sparks

Tags: google-plus

This afternoon, a Google Sparks query on a particular brand of footwear returns twenty results, of which twelve are low-content or nonsensical splogs.  Is there a way to block sites in Sparks?  I can Send Feedback twelve times, highlighting each of the splog paragraphs, but it is fiddly, and does not appear immediately to prevent the sites from being returned by a subsequent query.

None of the splog results appears within the first two pages of a traditional Google search query.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using the little "Send feedback" hidden in the bottom right-hand corner.

It's pretty sweet. It takes a full screenshot and allows you to highlight specific areas.

Google takes spam pretty seriously, so highlight the "sblogs" in question and send it to them with the keyword "spam" in your description.